# What is the purpose/meaning of the @ sign in such a string like this one: 'username'@'host' in mySQL statements?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if I'm asking some banal question but I couldn't find out what the @ symbol means in, for instance, this mysql statement: "CREATE USER 'username'@'somehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword'". Is it a delimiter in this case or something else?